# Is it possible to add a face from a pic to a person without Face ID?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

Is it possible to add a face from a pic to a person without Face ID ?

I don’t want to call face detect API cause I have face rectangle data in pics . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this official doc](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523b) , You can add a face to a person if you have rectangle data
with param `targetFace`.

I have [posted an answer before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038397/specifying-bounding-boxes-when-adding-faces-to-large-person-group-person-in-cogn/58055539#58055539) with details steps to do that , pls have a check if it is helpful for you .

Beside large person group , it works for person group too.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Thanks！I will have a check.